# Is it possible to generate Sitecore Search Scope across the entire tenant?

Tags: sxa, content-search, sxa-search

I have a requirement to display pages based on two different templates on two separate sites.

For example: Let's say I have one site called `Site A` and another site called `Site B`. In `Site A`, I have a template called `Template A` and in `Site B`, I have a template called `Template B`.

I need to display all the pages based on `Template A` and `Template B` in the 'Site A' directory page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend search scope in `Sitecore SXA` with `Solr`. You can take reference from below URL for this

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/extend-search.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the support and the response. It helped me to solve this.

Comment: @AnjaliNirmani - Great to see this that it resolved your issue. Can you please mark it as useful answer. So that if anyone face same problem, they could take reference from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extent your search and want to include other sites then use below steps.

1. Go to /`sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings` and in the Search
   Criteria section, in the Associated Content field, click the sites
   that you want to include in the search. If you leave this field
   empty, only the current site will be searched.
2. Search Scope: Both `Search Box` and `Search Results` require a Scope to be set in their components properties. These scopes are found under `/sitecore/content/<Tenant>/<Site>/Settings/Scopes/` where you can create one to basically define the limits of the search in the site. For example, you can specify there an item path for which sitecore would start searching at and/or specify which kinds of items via `templates` are allowed to appear in the Search Results.

For more details about search scopes, you can refer to this article.

https://bienangelo.com/sxa-search-with-multiple-checklist-filters/